# How to randomize file-names with BATCH file command string?

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, command-line, rename

I have 1 directory contains 85 *.bmp images. The names of each files looks as following:

```
1.bmp
2.bmp
3.bmp
4.bmp
... (and so on...)
```

I need to automatic randomize file-names, but the names have to be numbers from the 1 to 85 range.
As result for example 1.bmp can be renamed in 72.bmp, the if I run command string again this 72.bmp can be renamed in 15.bmp. But it couldn't be 86.bmp of 157.bmp, because it's out of range 1 to 85.
PS
The names one time can't be the same, of course.

How it could be done with simple windows command prompt and batch file ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your "method" of change problem requirements each time the previous ones are  solved, that force us to rewrite and test code several times, nor the fact that you state the new requirements in comments of certain answers only so the readers are forced to read _all comments_ in order to know the requirements, instead of post all of them in the original question... `:(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another one. Coded as a subroutine uses a similar idea in @Aacini's answer. Read all the files into an array, and shuffle the array, renaming as the shuffle processes files.

In this case, files are renamed one by one to a temporary extension to avoid collisions while processing the list. This temporary extension is later removed. That means one rename operation for each file and one rename operation over the full list of files.

There is no requirements in file name format, number of files (limited to environment memory) or special characters in file names.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "workingFolder=%~1"
    if not defined workingFolder set "workingFolder=%cd%"

    set "fileExtension=%~2"
    if not defined fileExtension set "fileExtension=*"

    call :randomizeFolderFiles "%workingFolder%" "%fileExtension%"

    endlocal
    exit /b

:randomizeFolderFiles folder fileExtension
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 
    set "count=0"

    pushd "%~1"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
        dir /b /a-d "*.%~2" 2^>nul ^| findstr /n "^"
    ') do ( set "f[%%a]=%%b" & set "count=%%a" & set "a[%%a]=%%a" )

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /l %%a in (%count% -1 1) do (
        set /a "e=(!random! %% %%a)+1"
        set /a "t=a[!e!]"
        set /a "a[!e!]=a[%%a]"
        for %%c in (!t!) do ren "!f[%%a]!" "!f[%%c]!.$random"
    )
    endlocal
    if %count% gtr 0 ren "*.%~2.$random" "*."
    popd 

    endlocal & exit /b
```

The full list of files is readed in `f[]`, and the indexes in `a[]`. The array `a` is shuffled using a Fisher-Yates in place shuffle. In each iteration of the loop, the element `%%a` (with `%%a` from `%count%` to `0`) is swapped with a random element `!e!` in the range `0..%%a`, leaving in `%%a` the final element for this position of the array. So rename `f[%%a]` (in the original list the file in position `%%a`) to `f[!e!]` (the random selected file in the shuffle)

**edited** to adapt to comments

To pass the file extension as argument to the batch file (or to directly set the value in the `fileExtension` variable) only the `bmp` is needed.

```
doRandomize.cmd "c:\somewhere" "bmp"
```

Or, from code,

```
set "fileExtension=bmp"
```

To make it work across subdirectories, the `call` line can be changed to something like

```
for /r "%workingFolder%" /d %%d in (.) do call :randomizeFolderFiles "%%~fd" "%fileExtension%"
```

That is , iterate over the list of folders and for each one call the randomize procedure.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tested it. I become one problem: if set "fileExtension=*" to set "fileExtension=*.bmp" script doesn't work for me. Whats going wrong? And one more thing - is thre any possibility to make this script working for multiple subfolders (all sub folders in workingFolder) ?

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко, sorry, i should have included it. Use `set "fileExtension=bmp"`

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко, answer updated to show how to handle recursion

Comment: Dear MC ND. This script works even better then I can imagine! It's very powerful and flexible. This one can be configured to cover all my needs! Thank you very much. You and the other SO-people are awesome! You are great and very helpful. T.H.A.N.K Y.O.U

Answer (score 2):

not sure how simple it is:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set set_flag=0

pushd "%~1"
for /f %%A in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b *.bmp ^| find /v /c ""') do set files_count=%%A

for /l %%# in (1;1;!files_count!) do (

    set set_flag=0
    set /a rnd=!RANDOM!*85/32768+1

    if not defined rand_!rnd! (
        rem echo setting !rnd! to %%# in outer function 
        set rand_!rnd!=%%#
    ) else (
        call :forward !rnd! %%#
        if !set_flag! EQU 0 call :backward !rnd! %%#
    )
)

rem set rand_

for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==_" %%a in ('set rand_') do (
    rem echo %%a.bmp to %%b.bmp_ 
    REN %%a.bmp %%b.bmp_   2>nul 
)

for /l %%# in (1=1=!files_count!) do (
    rem echo %%#.bmp_ to %%#.bmp
    ren %%#.bmp_ %%#.bmp
)
endlocal
popd
exit /b 0
:backward
    set up_limit=%~1
    set set_to=%~2

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /l %%$ in (!up_limit! , -1 , 1 ) do (
        if not defined rand_%%$ (
            set inner_rnd=%%$
            rem echo setting !inner_rnd! to %set_to% from :backward
            set /a rand_!inner_rnd!=%set_to%
            goto :break_back
        )
    )
    endlocal && goto :eof
    :break_back
    endlocal & (
      set rand_%inner_rnd%=%set_to%
    )
:forward
    set down_limit=%~1
    set set_to=%~2

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /l %%$ in (!down_limit! , 1 , !files_count! ) do (
        if not defined rand_%%$ (
            set inner_rnd=%%$
            rem echo setting !inner_rnd! to %set_to% from :forward
            set /a rand_!inner_rnd!=%set_to%
            set set_flag=1
            goto :break_forward
        )
    )
    endlocal && goto :eof
    :break_forward
    endlocal & (
      set rand_%inner_rnd%=%set_to%
      set set_flag=%set_flag%
    )
```

I thought it will be madness to wait all the numbers to be filled only by waiting `%random%` to generate all numbers.So I've created :backward and :forward functions for faster generation.

**EDIT** 10:05:57 p.m. (GMT + 0:00) - rename part fixed.
**EDIT**  edited according to the new requirements. Now it accepts the directory as a first argument and counts the `.bpm` files.
To execute this to all sub-directories (lets say the script is saved as `randomizer.bat`) use this with the actual path to the script:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%# in (*) do call c:\randomizer.bat "%%~#"
```

Comment: npocmaka, as I read the question, the task is to rename one file at a time.  Your code looks a lot more complicated than that. :)

Comment: @foxidrive - As I understand the question there are files from 1 to 85. The OP wants these names reused but randomized..

Comment: He says he wants one file renamed, then another one renamed when he runs the command again.  The question is very unclear.

Comment: @foxidrive - I've red the question again.Now I'm totally not sure if he wants one file renamed or all of them  :-\

Comment: I think you are right - he needs all 85 filenames randomised.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please tell me is there any possibility to make this code independent for the files count? Let say, directory contains n-count of BMP files. And we need to randomize all of them. File names are numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко -ok.Wait just a minute.

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко - now count of files is stored in `files_count` variable.You can set it as an argument by `set /a files_count=%%~1` or you can automaticaly count the files.

Comment: @npocmaka Thank you very much! Please tell me, can I run this script from main folder to make actions with files from subfolder? Subfolder directory contains BMP files is named "IMAGES"

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко after `set files_count=xx` add `pushd=IMAGES` and before `exit /b 0` add `popd` to return to original directory

Comment: @npocmaka THANK YOU!!! Now I see, that I did it correct too in my notepad. Please tell me, is it possible to make this randomize-names actions in all sub-subfolders? Let say, RootDir\Images\(and there are Img1; Pictures; Imagetop; Screens; bitmaps and other folders?)

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко  Please ALWAYS reveal the actual task in your question. It wastes peoples time by writing and testing code that has to be changed and tested again and again when the task changes.

Comment: @foxidrive Dear foxidrive. I'm sorry to ask such many questions, but for my needs I need to have all algorithms, because I will use all of them. It's not just only one task, there are 5 different tasks. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко  That's fine.  Just put ALL the details in your initial question.

Comment: @ЄвгенЄвтушенко - change the `pushd` line to `pushd %%~1`.Lets say the script is saved as `randomizer.bat` then in another script use this `for /d /r %%# in (*) do echo call c:\randomizer.bat %%~#` . But if all directories has a different count of files I'll have to rewrite the script       ...again.

Comment: @npocmaka Thank you again. I've tested it in many ways. I found the last script doesn't do its job. I've created a testing folder with all possible variant with names and run it with other bat file using (for /d /r %%# in (*) do call c:\randomizer.bat "%%~#") string. After processing I have: Susub1 (contains files 1,2,3 bmp) - no effect. Susub2 (contains files 1,2,3,4,5 bmp) - file 4.bmp was renamed to "5.bmp_", other no effected. Susub3 (contains only one file 7.bmp) - no effect. (part one ends here, the last part in next comment)

Comment: @npocmaka Susub4 (contains files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 bmp) - 5.bmp was renamed to 6.bmp_ others - no effect. Susub5 (contains files 5,6,7,8,9 bmp) - file 6.bmp renamed to "2.bmp", others - no effect. Susub6 (contains files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 bmp) - 4.bmp was renamed to "8.bmp_". So, I sorry to say, last script don't work. But thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This code should randomise all BMP filenames:

**EDIT:** The code now counts the number of BMP files in the folder.  `1.bmp 2.bmp 3.bmp ... nn.bmp` etc

```
@echo off
if not exist *.bmp echo no bmp files found&pause&goto :EOF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for %%a in (*.bmp) do set /a num+=1
for /L %%a in (1,1,%num%) do (set A%%a=&set B%%a=)

:loop
for /L %%a in (1,1,%num%) do (
   for /L %%b in (1,1,500) do (
      if not defined A%%a set /a "B=(!random! %% %num%) + 1" & if not defined B!b! set A%%a=ren "%%a.bmp" "!b!.zzz" & set B!b!=1 
   )
)
for /L %%c in (1,1,%num%) do if "!A%%c!"=="" goto :loop  
for /L %%c in (1,1,%num%) do !A%%c!
ren *.zzz *.bmp
pause
```

Comment: But if all files from `1.bmp` to `85.bmp` already exist then the `%var2%.bmp` will exist in all cases?

Comment: I have created .bmp files with `for /l %a in (1,1,85) do break>%a.bmp`  (they exist - at least that's clear in the question). But this gave me endless : `renaming "xx.bmp" to "yy.bmp" will fail, trying again...` I think you need a temp file name different from the originals.

Comment: @npocmaka I've changed my code to randomise all 85 filenames.  The first code only randomised one file but as I explained it would only work if there was a filename free - so less than 85 files.

Comment: Now it works.To be that all the files were renamed I've executed : `dir /b /o:d /t:c *.bmp`

Comment: Thank you very much! Please tell me is there any possibility to make this code independent for the files count? Let say, directory contains n-count of BMP files. And we need to randomize all of them. File names are numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: @foxidrive Thank you, I'll try it in a minute!

Comment: @foxidrive Thank you very much. Ive tried to to put this batch-file script into root file, but it cannot find any bmp-files. Then I've put it into the folder with bmp directly and I've run it there. it doesn't work for me yet. Command line says that it can't find the file. and upper I see one column with 1.bmp, 2.bmp, 3.bmp list and right-hand second column with reversed filenames 3.zzz, 2.zzz, 3.zzz.

Comment: I forgot to remove the 'echo` which show me that it worked.  Try the batch file now in a folder with the BMP files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that is independent of the count of files (though it does require them to be named 1.bmp to n.bmp).

It also uses a +1 slide so that it doesn't rely on %random% eventually hitting all possible values.  This could cost you a small amount of randomness, but once you have a solution, you can always run it multiple times.

Also doesn't require enabledelayedexpansion, though I think I work at the only place left in the world that doesn't use it.

```
setlocal
set TEMPPREFIX=__TEMPBITMAP_
set FILEEXTENSION=bmp

for /f %%a in ('dir/b *.%FILEEXTENSION% ^| find /C "."') do set countfiles=%%a

for /L %%a in (1 1 %countfiles%) do call :RandomizeSingleFile %%a

:: Strip temp prefix from all files
for /L %%a in (1 1 %countfiles%) do ren %TEMPPREFIX%%%a.%FILEEXTENSION% %%a.%FILEEXTENSION%

endlocal & goto :eof

:RandomizeSingleFile
setlocal
set oldfilename=%1.%FILEEXTENSION%

set /a num=(%random% %% %countfiles%) + 1

:GetNewNumber_iterate
set newfilename=%TEMPPREFIX%%NUM%.%FILEEXTENSION%

if exist %newfilename% (
  set /a num=%num%+1
  if %num% GEQ %countfiles% set num=1
  goto :GetNewNumber_iterate
)

ren %oldfilename% %newfilename%

endlocal & goto :eof
```

Tested on directories containing 8, 25, and 500 bmp files.

Comment: Just commenting that the other solutions can be run more than once too.  My code is sloppy in the way that it collects the random details, but it's quite quick too, and lean with code. :)

Comment: @foxidrive That's fair. I didn't mean to exclude, and I updated the wording.  If I had realized there were two other good solutions already posted, I might not have bothered, but since I already wrote the code... :)  It is interesting that all three solutions use different algorithms though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please tell me, can I run this script from main folder to make actions with files from subfolder? Subfolder directory contains BMP files is named "IMAGES"

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below rename any number of *.bmp files in current folder up to a maximum of 999 and does not require any format in the file names. Also, I think this is the fastest way to achieve this process.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load file names and create a list of numbers in natural order
rem with a separation space and three characters each
set i=0
set "list="
for %%a in (*.bmp) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "file[!i!]=%%a"
   set "num=   !i!"
   set "list=!list!!num:~-4!"
)
set "list=%list% "

rem Extract random elements from the list of numbers
rem and use they to rename the files
for /L %%i in (%i%,-1,1) do (
   set /A "randElem=!random! %% %%i * 4"
   for %%r in (!randElem!) do for /F "delims=" %%s in ("!list:~%%r,4!") do (
      for /F %%a in ("%%s") do ECHO ren "!file[%%i]!" "%%a.bmp"
      set "list=!list:%%s = !"
   )
)
```

Note that the `ren` commands are just displayed in the screen, *NOT* executed. If the commands are correct, remove the `ECHO` part in order to execute they.